# Issue when substracting 8 or more days to a select with week days using modulus using javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I have a select which options are the days of the week. I would like to add/substract days to a current selected day.

The issue i'm having is when i have to substract 8 or more days to the current day. I'm getting undefined. I know i'm out of range but i can't get the right solution for this case...

I have found new fail, if its sunday ,and add 1 day, gives undefined.

When i'm adding 8 or more days seems to work fine..

What i'm missing?
Regards

```js
var days = ["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"];
var select = document.getElementById("daysSelector");
function sumDays(index, numDays) {
 var i;
 console.log('index: ' + index);
 if (numDays < 0){
   
  var diff = parseInt(index) + parseInt(numDays);
     console.log(diff);
  
  if (diff < 0){ 
   
   i = days.length + diff; // Here is the problem
      
  }else{
   i = parseInt(diff) -  parseInt(numDays % days.length);
    
  }
 }else{
  
  i = parseInt(index) + parseInt(numDays % days.length); 
   }
 

 return days[i];
  }
var text = document.getElementById("days");
document.getElementById("addDays").onclick = function() { 

console.log(sumDays(select.value,text.value ));
}
```

```html
<select id="daysSelector">
       <option value="0">Monday</option>
       <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
       <option value="2">Wed</option>
    <option value="3">Thursday</option>
    <option value="4">Friday</option>
    <option value="5">Saturday</option>
    <option value="6">Sunday</option>
 </select>
 <input type="number" id="days"><br>
 <button id="addDays">Add Days</button><br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would fix the issue (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MoJdYG):

```
function sumDays(index, numDays) {
    var isNegative = parseInt(numDays, 10) > 0 ? false : true;
    var i = parseInt(index, 10) + parseInt(numDays, 10) % days.length;

    if (isNegative) {
        i = days.length + i;
    }

    return days[i % days.length];
}
```

Comment: The problem is on if (diff < 0).. The solution add a new issue..Regards

Comment: can you let me know the input values you entered? i can give it a try

Comment: Sure. Try add -8 and the selector on monday .Click button.  It should give Sunday..but give undefined..

Comment: this should handle all your conditions now.

Comment: Yes it did! Thanks!!